# how do i position the content at the centre of the image

Tags: html, image, position

I want to position all the buttons and DB's under the image but in the middle.
I can use javascript, css or HTML so please respond in these languages.
Here is what I want. The content is c.

img
 c

Here is my code if you know how to help pls do:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>movieDB</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ps4.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MovieDB</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Credits</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Filter
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Comedy</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fantasy</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Kids</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">pg</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search Movie" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <h1 class="display-1 d-flex justify-content-center mb-5"><img src="https://www.freelogodesign.org/file/app/client/thumb/da9eb726-0742-4b5b-a19a-7c42fcaa54ec_200x200.png?1581566782305" alt=""> </h1>
    <img class="m-0 mx-md-5 col-sm-12 col-md-4 d-block mb-3" src="https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/LVEAAOSwIttddvIz/s-l400.jpg" alt="">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger ml-5 p-2 ml-md-5" type="submit">❤</button>
    <h3 class="d-inline border border-success rounded-pill px-5">DB: 7.9</h3>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger mr-5" type="submit">Search</button>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what your looking for:

Your size adjustment seems to be `m-0 mx-md-5 col-sm-12 col-md-4 d-block mb-3`. So I just reused them (I think you shouldn't need that much of class to make it work, it is not good for efficiency).

Anyway, there is you answer:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>movieDB</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ps4.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MovieDB</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Credits</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Filter
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Comedy</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fantasy</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Kids</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">pg</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search Movie" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <h1 class="display-1 d-flex justify-content-center mb-5"><img src="https://www.freelogodesign.org/file/app/client/thumb/da9eb726-0742-4b5b-a19a-7c42fcaa54ec_200x200.png?1581566782305" alt=""> </h1>
    <div class="m-0 mx-md-5 col-sm-12 col-md-4 d-block mb-3">
    </div>
    <img class="m-0 mx-md-5 col-sm-12 col-md-4 d-block mb-3" src="https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/LVEAAOSwIttddvIz/s-l400.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="m-0 mx-md-5 col-sm-12 col-md-4 d-block mb-3">
        <div class="text-center" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger ml-5 p-2 ml-md-5" style="
margin: 0!important;" type="submit">❤</button>
        <h3 class="d-inline border border-success rounded-pill px-5">DB: 7.9</h3>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger mr-5" style="
margin: 0!important;" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And one more thing to say, your buttons size could not fit your 33% width design when the window resized to a larger scale.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrapped the buttons in a DIV and added the text-center class to put the buttons in the middle

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>movieDB</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ps4.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MovieDB</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Credits</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Filter
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Comedy</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fantasy</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Kids</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">pg</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search Movie" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <h1 class="display-1 d-flex justify-content-center mb-5"><img src="https://www.freelogodesign.org/file/app/client/thumb/da9eb726-0742-4b5b-a19a-7c42fcaa54ec_200x200.png?1581566782305" alt=""> </h1>
    <img class="m-0 mx-md-5 col-sm-12 col-md-4 d-block mb-3" src="https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/LVEAAOSwIttddvIz/s-l400.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger ml-5 p-2 ml-md-5" type="submit">❤</button>
    <h3 class="d-inline border border-success rounded-pill px-5">DB: 7.9</h3>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger mr-5" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but I want it at the center of the image

Comment: You mean in front of the image?

Comment: Run the code snippet I posted it is at the bottom and centered

Comment: but when it's full screen it's at the center of the page

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>movieDB</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ps4.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MovieDB</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Credits</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Filter
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Comedy</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fantasy</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Kids</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">pg</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search Movie" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <h1 class="display-1 d-flex justify-content-center mb-5"><img src="https://www.freelogodesign.org/file/app/client/thumb/da9eb726-0742-4b5b-a19a-7c42fcaa54ec_200x200.png?1581566782305" alt=""> </h1>
<!--i have taken new div(flex box)  for image-->
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <img class="m-0 mx-md-5 col-sm-12 col-md-4 d-block mb-3" src="https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/LVEAAOSwIttddvIz/s-l400.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
<!--i have taken new div(flex box)  for buttons-->
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger ml-5 p-2 ml-md-5" type="submit">❤</button>
        <h3 class="d-inline border border-success rounded-pill px-5">DB: 7.9</h3>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger mr-5" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you briefly explain what you did to make it work? I will be very helpful for other users that stumble upon this question.